# Problem with MySQL query to recordset - possibly caused by move from MySQL 4 to MySQL 5

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website with a sales and wanted page, which uses a query to return all of the sales & wanted ads into a recordset. It's been working for 4-5years without incident, but suddenly stopped working on Friday. My ISP tell me they have implemented v5 of MySQL, which seems to have caused the problem.

The query is below:

```
$query = "select * from $table order by uidno desc limit $from,$max_results";
```

It's executed via the following command

```
$recordset = mysql_query($query);
    if($recordset == false)
    {
        echo("Could not retrieve comment. Please try later<br>");
        echo("060211<br>");
        return;
```

It's no longer able to load the comments into the recordset. Also the statement to populate the table is no longer populating the fields in the table correctly, though a new row is being created.
The statement is below:

```
$inputdata = "INSERT INTO $table(date,name,email,suggestion) values('$today','$inputname','$email','$suggestion')";
```

And it is executed via:

```
$outcome = mysql_query($inputdata);
```

The structure of the table is as follows:

```
uidno int(11) extra=AUTO_INCREMENT Null=no default = none
date date default 0000-00-00
Name varchar(60)
Email varchar (60) Null=yes Default = NULL
Suggestion blob attrbutes=binary null=no
```

Please help - I don't understand what changes I need to make to the syntax to make these queries compatible with MYSQL v5.

#### Update:

I added the echo mysql_error(); and it appears to output the following:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10,10' at line 1

So this indicates an error in the syntax - but I've no idea what the error is.

Comment: What errors do you get? What does a `echo mysql_error();` output?

Comment: I'm guessing your PHP interpreter was also upgraded, that this has nothing to do with MySQL changing, it's actually the loss of `magic_quotes_gpc` setting (deprecated long ago)... no longer are variables being created automatically based on the URL. You have to read from `$_GET` yourself. You tried to pull a page name form the URL and subtract 1, but that variable is no longer automatically created, so you end up with a negative multiplied when computing the offset/limit.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which **must both be nonnegative integer constants** (except when using prepared statements).

Answer (score 0):

> Column, index, stored routine, and
>   event names are not case sensitive on
>   any platform, nor are column aliases

so your lowercase column names in code and upper case column names in mysql structure should not be the problem.

Comment: All - many thanks for all of your help - I've now understood the absence of both $post and $get statements and corrected this - the site now works again thanks to your efforts...